# Complexity of $("SELECTOR").css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, time-complexity

I am trying to hide users that aren't in filtered users list.

For this, I am using this code

```
_.each(users, function (user) {
    var display_type = filtered_users.hasOwnProperty(user.email)? "block" : "none";
    $("label[for='" + user.email + "']").css({"display":display_type});
});
```

Where `users` is list of all user objects and `filtered_users` is list of email of filtered users.
I have around 1000 or more users to filter from. And seems like `$("label[for='" + user.email + "']").css({"display":display_type})` operation is taking too much time.

HTML:

```
<label class="checkbox" for="user1@gmail.com">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="user1@gmail.com"> Cordelia Lear (cordelia@zulip.com)
</label>
<label class="checkbox" for="user2@gmail.com">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="user2@gmail.com"> Cordelia Lear (cordelia@zulip.com)
</label>
```

Can someone explain what's the complexity of `$("label[for='" + user.email + "']").css({"display":display_type})`? Any possible way to improvise that?

Comment: `.css()` shouldn't be a bottleneck here. How long is your `users`  list?

Comment: Around 1000 or more users.

Comment: Can you add some users html?

Comment: Added html example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `$("label[for='" + user.email + "']")` is the part that slows you down. For every user, jquery's sizzle engine have to go over all of the labels in the page, and choose the exact one, so it's at least o(n) * o(n) for iterating the users - o(n2).

To solve that you can create a map of labels by emails once (the same thing you do for `filtered_users`), and then with o(1), find the element and change the display:

```js
var usersMap = $('.users')
  .find('label')
  .toArray()
  .reduce(function(map, user) {
    var $user = $(user);
    var email = $user.attr('for');
    map[email] = $user;
    return map;
  }, {});

var users = [
         { email: 'user1@gmail.com' }, 
         { email: 'user2@gmail.com'}
        ];

var filtered_users = { 'user1@gmail.com': true };

users.forEach(function(user) {
  var display_type = filtered_users.hasOwnProperty(user.email) ? "block" : "none";
  usersMap[user.email].css({
    "display": display_type
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="users">
  <label class="checkbox" for="user1@gmail.com">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="user1@gmail.com">Cordelia Lear (cordelia@zulip.com)
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox" for="user2@gmail.com">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="user2@gmail.com">Cordelia Lear (cordelia@zulip.com)
  </label>
</div>
```